# Centos 6.5 Samba 3 You don't have permission from user

Tags: centos6, samba

I have an error while i want to copy my file in **centos 6.5** using samba to my **windows 7** folder.
This is the error message :

```
you need permission to perform this action
You require permission from ERP\hao to make change to this file.

[global]
    workgroup = MYGROUP
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    # max 50KB per log file, then rotate
    max log size = 50
    security = user
[erp]
    comment = ERP
    path = /opt/erp
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    printable = no
    browseable = no
    create mask = 0777
    create mode = 0777
    directory mode = 0777
    share modes = yes
    force user = hao
    force group = hao
    read only = no
```

File that i want to copy location :

> /opt/erp/mve

my samba path

> /opt/erp

```
[hao@erp mve]$ stat -c '%a %n' *
777 7841e10a957d4bceb2205632c49543af.ygk
777 p18i13847jgnl1s91kujqlh1t9c3.ygk

[hao@erp erp]# ls -l mve/
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 hao hao  63467455 Mar 10 21:38 7841e10a957d4bceb2205632c49543af.ygk
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 hao hao 111912448 Mar 10 21:46 p18i13847jgnl1s91kujqlh1t9c3.ygk

[root@erp erp]# smbd --version
Version 3.6.9-167.el6_5


[hao@erp erp]# ls -l
drwxrwxrwx.  2 hao hao       4096 Mar 11 09:42 mve
```

I Can copy all files in /opt/erp except in mve folder.
Please help, how to fix this problem. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: probably better asked on ServerFault or SuperUser than here... but if I recall, Windows Vista and Up, requires by default a password for network file sharing. You can disable it though in your network configs on your windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me on Windows 7 when using CentOS 6.5.

http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/how-to-install-samba-server-on-centos-6/

Slight changes to instructions..

1. The workgroup will need to change based on yours specifically (set value in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`).
2. Use `\\192.168.x.x\` instead of `\\centos` on Windows.
3. You'll need to create the folders `/samba` and `/samba/share` and set permissions appropriately.
4. If your OS doesn't have nano (per the instructions), then install that before you begin... `yum install nano`
5. Run restart commands (2 of them) at the end twice, since the shutdown won't apply.  Make sure you get OK on both.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out to be related to the SELinux security context.

I had to run the command `chcon -t samba_share_t /<path>/<to>/<share> -R`.

Now i can create and change files in the shared folder.